# Dirichlet distribution: posteriors and priors of distribution

Tags: complexity-theory, quantum-advantage, probability, linear-algebra

Let $|\psi\rangle \in \mathbb{C}^{2n}$ be a random quantum state such that $ |\langle z| \psi \rangle|^{2} $ is distributed according to a $\text{Dirichlet}(1, 1, \ldots, 1)$ distribution, for $z \in \{0, 1\}^{n}$.

Let $z_{1}, z_{2}, \ldots, z_{k}$ be $k$ samples from this distribution (not all unique). Choose a $z^{*}$ that appears most frequently.

1. I am trying to prove:

$$\underset{|\psi\rangle}{\mathbb{E}}\big[|\langle z^{*}| \psi \rangle|^{2}\big] =  \underset{|\psi\rangle}{\mathbb{E}}\bigg[\underset{m}{\mathbb{E}}\big[|\langle z^{*}| \psi \rangle|^{2} ~| ~m\big]\bigg] = \mathbb{E}\bigg[\frac{1+m}{2^{n}+k}\bigg],$$
where $m$ is a random variable that denotes the frequency of $z^{*}$.

2. I am also trying to prove that for the collection $z_{1}, z_{2}, \ldots, z_{k}$
   $$\sum_{i \neq j}\mathrm{Pr}[z_{i} = z_{j}] =  {n \choose k}\frac{2}{2^{n} + 1}. $$

Basically, I am trying to trace the steps of Lemma $13$ (page 10) of this [quantum paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.08721.pdf). I realize that my questions have to deal with posteriors and priors of the chosen distribution (though I do not understand how they have been explicitly derived or used here. An explicit derivation will be helpful). Is there any resource where I can find quick formulas for calculating these for other distributions, like the Binomial distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ p_i = |\langle i | \phi \rangle|^2 \sim Dir(a_1, .., a_{2^n}) = Dir(1, .., 1) $ and $ m_i $ the occurences of outcome $ |i\rangle $ on samples $z_1, .. z_k$.

Since the Dirichlet distribution is the conjugate prior of the categorical (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Dirichlet_distribution&section=8#Conjugate_to_categorical/multinomial)), meaning

$ \bf{p} $ $| Z, (1, .. 1), $ $\bf{m} $ $ \sim Dir(2^n, $ $\bf{m} + 1$)

and using the formula for the mean value of Dirichlet we get

$ \mathbb{E}[p_{z*} | m] = \frac{m+1}{\sum_{j=1}^{2^n} (m_j + 1)} = \frac{m+1}{2^n + k} $

For the second claim, take $ i \neq j $ and compute
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}[z_i = z_j] 
&= \int \mathbb{P}[z_i = z_j | (p_1, .. p_{2^n})] \cdot f(p_1, .. p_{2^n}) \\
&= \int \sum_{k=0}^{2^n} p_k^2 \cdot f(p_1, .. p_{2^n}) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{2^n} \mathbb{E}[p_k^2] \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{2^n} \frac{2}{2^n(2^n + 1)} = \frac{2}{2^n + 1}
\end{align*}

(the last equality holds since $ \bf{x} $ $ \sim Dir($$\bf{a}$) $ \implies \mathbb{E}[x_i^2] = \frac{a_i(a_i + 1)}{a_0(a_0 + 1)} $, $ a_0 = \sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i $.

This means that $ \sum_{i \neq j} \mathbb{P}[z_i = z_j] = {k \choose 2} \frac{2}{2^n + 1} $.

Comment: What is $Z$ in $p | Z, (1, \ldots, 1)$? And why is $\sum_{j = 1}^{2^{n}} (m_{j} + 1) = 2^{n} + k$? Also, how many parameters are needed to specify the Dirichlet distribution - I see that you have used multiple parameters at different times?

Comment: By $ Z $ i  refer to the collections of all the samples $ z_1, .. z_k $. Also $ \sum_{j=1}^{2^n} (m_j + 1) = \sum_{j=1}^{2^n} m_j + \sum_{j=1}^{2^n}1 = k + 2^n $ since the first sum simply counts the number of samples. In general you need $2^n $ concentration paramaters $ a_i $ for the Dirichlet distribution to generate points in the $2^n-1$ simplex. Finally,  i only used different parameters for the prior and the posterior distributions

Comment: I define $ m_i $ to be the number of occurences of $|i\rangle$ and then i write $m_{z*} = m $. $ \sum_{j=1}^{2^n} m_j = \sum_{j=1}^{2^n} \sum_{l=1}^{k} \delta_{z_l, j} = \sum_{l=1}^{k} \sum_{j=1}^{2^n}  \delta_{z_l, j} = \sum_{l=1}^{k} 1 = k $

Comment: $ \mathbb{P}[z_i = z_j | (p_1, .., p_{2^n})] = \sum_{k=0}^{2^n} \mathbb{P}[z_i = k | (p_1, .., p_{2^n}), z_j = k] \cdot \mathbb{P}[z_j = k |  (p_1, .., p_{2^n})] = \sum_{k=0}^{2^n} p_k \cdot p_k = \sum_{k=0}^{2^n} p_k^2 $ since $z_i, z_j $ independent. For the integral sign i used that $ \int p_k^2 \cdot f(p_1, .. p_{2^n}) = \mathbb{E}[p_k^2] $ since $f $ is the p.d.f

Comment: A stupid question, why is $Z$ distributed according to the categorical distribution? And, what happens when $Z$ has a categorical distribution but the $p_{i}$s have a different distribution, like a binomial distribution? Will the posterior still be a Dirichlet?

Comment: Well, each $ z_k $ takes the value $ |i \rangle $ with probability $ p_i $. This means that $ z_k | $ $\bf{p}$ is distributed according to the categorical. The "valid" distributions for $(p_1, .. p_{2^n}) $ are multivariate distributions defined on a simplex, since it must hold that $ \sum_{i} p_i = 1 $. The binomial is not one of them. For other "valid" distributions, i don't believe that there are some nice formulas that you can write down but honestly, i don't know.

Comment: Finally, when we write $\mathbb{E}(p_{z^{*}}|m)$, do we actually mean $\mathbb{E}(p_{z^{*}}| Z, m)$?  Why isn't there a summation over $Z = (z_{1}, \ldots, z_{k})$ in the expectation?

Comment: Correct. This is what i mean.

Comment: So, when we take the expectation over $m$, are we also, implicitly, taking it over $Z$?

Comment: We are taking the expectation condtional on $\bf{m}$. If we know Z, then we know $\bf{m}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113785/discussion-between-blackhat18-and-tsgeorgios).